# Grails spring security ldap plugin

Tags: spring, grails, ldap, spring-ldap

I am writing a project using Grails and Spring Security. I want to use LDAP for it. As such, I installed the `spring-security-core` and  `spring-security-LDAP` plugins. I got the login to work for spring security. I also have LDAP running and configured in Grails. I would rather not post that source, but it has the needed `springsecurity.ldap.contexts/search/authorities`.

The problem is I can't get it to stop searching locally. If I try to use a name from LDAP, it fails, yet if I use one from bootstrap it works. I know this has been asked before, but I looked through the answer and got a 404 for some important parts. My question is nearly identical to [this person's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035402/how-to-use-ldap-plugin-on-grails), Although, it would seem his issue was never resolved.

Comment: Do you have the following in Config.groovy?
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['ldapAuthProvider',
'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']